# IIS 6 Cannot load type from global.asax

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-6, iis-10

I am facing a peculiar issue where my deployed code works as expected on IIS10 on my machine. However on a separate server with IIS6 it produces an error .

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Namespace.Global'
```

So far I have done the following checks

- Ensured that the Namespace in the Global.asax is the same as the Project Namespace
- Global.asax properties set to "Build Action : Content" and Copy to Output 
  Directory: always

I have also tried the suggestions from the following posts but I havent found any successs

[Parser Load Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071220/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-sometype)

[Could not Load Type from Global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029104/visual-studio-cannot-load-type-from-global-asax)

[Could Not Load Type 'MyNameSpace.Global](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/485f7ff7-4428-43db-b715-2b8ef4cddb60/could-not-load-type-mynamespaceglobal?forum=asmxandxml)

Global.asax contents

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="Namespace.Global" %>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Aren't types case-sensitive?

Comment: Sorry it was typo let me edit the question.

Comment: So its "Namespace" (placeholder for my actual Namespace) and I havent edited/ renamed the Namespace in my project.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 you have any suggestions for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it , the application was  compiled on .NET framework 4.0 on my machine and the website on IIS 6 was configured on .NET Framework 1.xx .

After setting the configuration in the Website to .NET 4.0, the issue no longer appeared.

Hope this helps someone :)